# Object is of type 'unknown'.Vetur(2571) when populating a constant in TypeScript using Apollo

Tags: typescript, vue.js, apollo, quasar-framework, vetur

I am using the useQuery (from Apollo) to fetch data as follows:

```
const {
  result: fetchedResources,
  loading: fetchResourcesLoading,
  refetch: fetchResources,
  onError: apiError
} = useQuery(GET_RESOURCES, { limit: numberOfResults.value })
```

I use `fetchedResources` in a v-for to loop over data:

```
  <router-link
    v-for="resource in fetchedResources.resources"
    :key="resource.id"
    class="resource q-mb-md items-center text-black"
    tag="div"
  >
...
```

Any time I use `resource` I get the following error in Visual Studio:

```
Object is of type 'unknown'.Vetur(2571)
```

I assume the issue is I need to declare the type in the constant for each of the populate variables. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: What is the type of `fetchedResources`? Is it possible for you to pass type arguments to `useQuery` so that `fetchedResources` is properly typed?

Comment: I don't see `useQuery` in the Quasar documentation (https://quasar.dev/) or their repository (https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar).

Comment: fetchedResources is an Array I believe and useQuery is a feature for Apollo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Vetur has recently released 0.35.0 and it picked up a genuine error in the Typescript code for Apollo. These docs provided info on how to set the type for each array: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/